# Ahlfors pg.85,86 circles of Apollonius

Tags: complex-analysis

[Ahlfors pg85](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AChMq.png)

[Ahflors pg 86](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekcud.png)

On pg85 Ahflors mentions that the circles of Apollonius with limit points a and b, i.e the $C_2$ circles are circles that satisfy this equation $|\frac{z-a}{z-b}|= \frac{p}{|k|}$. However, on page 86, he says that when the limit points are 0 and $\infty$ $C_1$ are the lines through the origin, which makes sense since $C_1$ are circled through the points a and b. What doesn't make sense to me is why $C_2$ are concentric circles (I'm not sure where the origin of the circles is either). Since I'm thinking that the ratio $|\frac{z-a}{z-b}|= \frac{p}{|k|}$ will always be $0$ no matter what the value of z is. So how can $C_2$ be concentric circles?